# Setting static/template filepath to sibbling/parent folder in flask

Tags: python, flask

Well consider the following layout:

```
/
static/
    static_path_file.html
server/
    app.py
```

I notice that when I create a flask application in app.py:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="../static")
```

I can't select the static path as per above. Flask still "expects" the static files to be a subset of `server/` and ignores the "../" in front. How would I configure flask to serve from a sibbling folder?

---

I've also tried the suggestion of setting the root folder of the flask app:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="static", root_path="../")
```

But this (or even setting both root & static to the parent folder) doesn't seem to work.

Comment: try setting the root path parameter

Comment: @sea that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You just should set static_folder as absolute path to static folder.

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder=os.path.abspath("../static")
```